# Rss feeds date format error xcode ios

Tags: ios, xcode, rss

Hi can anyone help me out from this error:

while rss feed parsing.it showing null in tableview cell and crashing the app as well.

Could not parse RFC822 date: "Mon, 27 Aug 2012 06:00:01 PT" Possibly invalid format.

Comment: Can you show us how you're parsing the date? Also, shouldn't "PT" be either "PST" or "PDT"?

Comment: @Rob:its working fine now i changed PT to PST thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it was a simple fix. I'll post an answer so you can click the checkmark next to the answer in order to "accept" the answer and officially close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [RFC822](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28) the time zone should probably be PST, or otherwise conform to the following format:

```
zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                            ; North American : UT
            /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
            /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
            /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
            /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
            /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                            ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                            ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
            / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                            ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```